# The error "RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task" occurs in Pyrogram

Tags: python, bots, python-asyncio, aiogram, pyrogram

I have 2 threads in main.py file, the first one is created via Thread (bot thread) the second one is the main python thread where Pyrogram runs [screenshot of main.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuefE.png)
But when I run the code, Pyrogram terminates code execution when it gets to the point of sending the error message "Timeout context manager should be used inside a task", here is the full log [full log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZgLG.png)

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-157' coro=<__send_message() done, defined at C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\services\trade.py:7> exception=RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used inside a task')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\services\trade.py", line 8, in __send_message
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=db.get_user_value('tg_id'), text=msg)
  File "C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 346, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1167, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 493, in _request
    with timer:
  File "C:\Programming\BybitTradeBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 705, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Here's the code that was used [userbot code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBvEA.png) [code from trade.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI55D.png)

If userbot is not given any asynchronous tasks, it does not cause an error "Timeout context manager should be used inside a task"

If run just Pyrogram, there are no problems and this code runs without any errors, even if it is asynchronous code

What is the cause of this error and how can it be fixed?

---

main.py

```py
import asyncio
from aiogram import executor
from threading import Thread

from loader import dp, logging
import handlers
from userbot import main_client


async def start(_):
    logging.info('The bot is up and running')
    print('[+] The bot is up and running')


def bot_thread():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        process = Thread(target=bot_thread)
        process.start()
        main_client(logging)  # Pyrogram
    except Exception as error:
        logging.warning(error)
        print(error)
```

userbot.py

```py
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler

from loader import logging as log
from config import USERBOT_API_HASH, USERBOT_API_ID, CHAT_ID_FOR_PARSING
from services.trade import do_futures_trade


last_photo_id = None


def main_client(logging):
    client = Client(name='my_bot', api_id=USERBOT_API_ID, api_hash=USERBOT_API_HASH)

    async def message_photo(client: Client, message):  # pass the chat ID or Username to the function
        global last_photo_id
        async for msg in client.get_chat_history(chat_id=CHAT_ID_FOR_PARSING, limit=1, offset_id=-1):  # looking at the end of the story
            try:
                if msg.photo and msg.caption and msg.photo.file_id != last_photo_id:  # if there's a photo
                    logging.info(f'A prediction was sent to the group file_id - {msg.photo.file_id} caption - {msg.caption}')
                    await client.download_media(msg.photo, file_name=f'forecast.jpg')  # Downloading a photo
                    last_photo_id = msg.photo.file_id
                    logging.info('A new forecast {msg.photo.file_id} has been sent')

                    do_futures_trade(msg.caption, client.loop)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(f"There's been an error {e}")

    client.add_handler(MessageHandler(message_photo, filters=filters.photo & filters.chat(chats=int(CHAT_ID_FOR_PARSING))))
    client.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_client(log)
```

trade.py

```py
from loader import bot
import asyncio
from services.connection_db import db

async def __send_message(msg):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=db.get_user_value('tg_id'), text=msg)

def send_msg(msg, client_loop):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(__send_message(msg), client_loop)

def do_futures_trade(msg, client_loop):
    send_msg(msg, client_loop)
    ...
```

handlers.py

```py
from loader import dp, bot

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Hello User")
```

Comment: Please share you code as a text and not as an image. In this way, others can easily copy and try it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I see that the first line in the traceback refers to line 8 in trade.py, and shows a function call `send_message`.  The code you supplied for trade.py does not contain this line.  Perhaps you could try again, and post the real code this time.  Please be more considerate when posting questions here so you don't waste everyone else's time.

Comment: Sorry, the wrong code was specified a bit in trade.py, but the general error "Timeout context manager should be used inside a task" persists